# Why is PM2 watching but not catching changes to code?

Tags: node.js, express, windows-server-2012, pm2, process-management

I read related posts on this question, but they don't help.

I'm running a Node-Express app in a windows environment using PM2 with pm2-windows-service.  Until today it's been running node just fine and reloading Node when I save changes to my code.  Today it stopped working.  When I make changes, Node still serves up the old code.  Even when I manually restart PM2.  Plus, when I manually start PM2 it rapidly restarts Node until I kill Node with Task Manager.

Furthermore, even when I kill PM2, delete the PM2 app, and try manually running Node or nodemon, I still get the old code.

Baffling.  Any theories?

Thank you!

Here's my ecosystem.config.js file:

```js
module.exports = {
  apps : [{
    name: 'sm_api',
    script: 'server/index.js',
    log_date_format  : "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm Z",

    // Options reference: https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/reference/ecosystem-file/
    args: 'one two',
    instances: 'max',
    error_file : "C:\\pm2_system\\.pm2\\logs\\sm-api-error",
    out_file: "C:\\pm2_system\\.pm2\\logs\\sm-api-out",
    autorestart: true,
    watch: true,
    max_restarts: 10,
    max_memory_restart: '1G',
    env: {
      NODE_ENV: 'development'
    },
    env_production: {
      NODE_ENV: 'production'
    },
    exec_mode: 'cluster'
  }],
};
```

Comment: if it "just" showed up and it pm2 restarts node all the time, there must be a problem with your code. Make sure you are watching for [uncaughtException](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception)

Comment: Thanks @japrescott.  Yes, I do have a problem with my code.  The change that is not being "seen" by PM2 is a change to comment out the bad line of code.  It won't "take".

Comment: yes, thats because you must have errors in your code, like a SyntaxError or a TypeError. If that happens, most file-system watchers cant/wont reload

Comment: @japrescott right you were.  There was a require statement that was also accessing the bad code.  Issue solved.  Thank you!